# Grep command to output in file

Tags: files, grep

```
grep -irm 1 "some_pattern" . | wc -l > myfile.txt
```

I used this command to find out the number of files having the given pattern. I want to output it in file. But I couldn't... what to add or remove ?

Comment: myfile.txt should have your results, what do you get from `cat myfile.txt`?

Comment: Are you sure there's no `mysqfile.txt` file? I don't see something wrong

Comment: What is your expected result and what the actual result?

Answer (score -3):

```
grep -irmc 1 "some_pattern" . > output.txt
```

Comment: This is not OP wants, actually OP's example should work by itself..